# How to use TimeDistributed layer with Concatenate in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following model.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers 

def get_model():
    input_img = keras.Input(shape=(None, 5, 5, 1), name='image')
    input_vec = keras.Input(shape=(None, 3), name='bvec')
    
    x = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Conv2D(50, 3, activation='relu'), name='conv_1')(input_img)
    x = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Flatten(), name='flatten')(x)
    x = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Concatenate(), name='concat')([x, input_vec])
    
    output = layers.GRU(units=10, name='gru')(tensor)
    
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_img, input_vec], outputs=output)

m = get_model()
```

As an input I have a series of images & vector pairs.

The general idea is that I want the series of images each to be fed through a CNN then concatenated with the series of associated input vectors, then passed onto an RNN unit. A similar idea can be found [on a medium blog](https://medium.com/smileinnovation/how-to-work-with-time-distributed-data-in-a-neural-network-b8b39aa4ce00), though in that post there is only one series of image inputs, no vector series.

The trouble happens at the Concatenate layer. Here is the end of the traceback:

```
TypeError: Dimension value must be integer or None or have an __index__ method, got value 'TensorShape([None, None, 450])' with type '<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.tensor_shape.TensorShape'>'
```

I imagine this probably is a syntactical error on my behalf.

How would I go about concatenating two inputs on a TimeDistributed basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To concatenate two tensors use the layer `Concatenate` with the axis properly set which in your case is 2.

#### Fixed code:

```
input_img = keras.Input(shape=(None, 5, 5, 1), name='image')
input_vec = keras.Input(shape=(None, 3), name='bvec')

x = layers.TimeDistributed(
    layers.Conv2D(50, 3, activation='relu'), name='conv_1')(input_img)

x = layers.TimeDistributed(
    layers.Flatten(), name='flatten')(x)

x = layers.Concatenate(axis=2)([x, input_vec])
output = layers.GRU(units=10, name='gru')(x)

model = keras.models.Model(
    inputs=[input_img, input_vec], outputs=output)

model.compile(loss='mse')

model.fit(
    [np.random.randn(8,4,5,5,1), np.random.randn(8,4,3)],
     y=np.random.randint(0,10,8))
```

Output:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 1ms/step - loss: 29.4364
```

Comment: Thank you, so the concatenation layer in effect is 'Time distributed' because presumably it's input dimensionality includes the time series dimension? 
In this case `axis=2` is equivalent to `axis=-1` which is the default?